# Headphones stopped working after enabling alsa

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I'm pretty sure there's an easy solution to my problem, but I've looked around and can't find it.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3/Windows 10.  Fresh reinstall and all has been well until tonight when I launched Audacity and got a msg about getting better performance with alsa (or something to that effect).  I did as I was told and ran the following command:

```
sudo snap connect audacity:alsa
```

Immediately my headphones stopped working.  I've checked all the settings I can think of and can find nothing wrong.  I've rebooted with the headphones plugged in and unplugged.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled Audacity (at first I though it was isolated to the app, but no).  The headphones work on Windows.

Clearly this has to do with the alsa command, and the message seemed to mention how to undo it, but I cannot remember how and cannot find instructions anywhere.  I think it has something to do with PulseAudio, but I REALLY don't know.

Please help.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: OK, found where I can get help with this.  Thanks anyway.